# Unable to install ray[tune] tune-sklearn

Tags: python, data-mining, anaconda3, ray-tune

I'm trying to install ray[tune] tune-sklearn on my machine but keeps failing. I'm using a MacBook Pro 2019 with Big Sur Version 11.6 and Python 3.9.7 (default, Sep 16 2021, 08:50:36) [Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin. All other packages I've tried to installed fine either using conda install or pip install except for this one. I'm struggling to find an answer online myself. I was on Python 3.8 but I removed this and installed 3.9 as I thought this was the problem. Apologies in advance, I'm new to data mining and still don't know a great deal yet.

I tried

```
conda install -c conda-forge -y ray-tune tune-sklearn
```

But got back this:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - ray-tune

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

I also tried

```
pip install ray[tune] tune-sklearn
```

But got back

```
zsh: no matches found: ray[tune]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Update:

I also tried

```
pip install 'ray[tune]'
```

And got back

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ray[tune] (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for ray[tune]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ray[tune]` is a library within the [Ray distributed compute project](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/#what-is-ray) that supports [scalable hyperparameter tuning](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/tune/index.html) -- not a stand-alone Python package. You should be able to install `ray` with the proper dependencies using:

```
pip install "ray[tune]"
```

After Ray has been installed, you can reference it within your Python project using either:

```py
import ray[tune]
```

or

```py
from ray import tune
```

Comment: Yeah that worked thanks, looks like the double quotes have to be used as I done pip install 'ray[tune]' and it failed.